# Loop Until Row Empty

Tags: excel, vba

I currently have the VBA below for creating PDFs for data in a row of another worksheet (Claims). I would like to get rid of the limit of row 10 and just have the loop continue until the row is blank.

```
'Exporting PDF'
Sub ExportingPDF()

Dim claimsSheet As Worksheet
Dim reportSheet As Worksheet

Set reportSheet = ActiveWorkbook.Sheets("Design")
Set claimsSheet = ActiveWorkbook.Sheets("Claims")

'Looping through each row'
For i = 2 To 10

'Generating Output - Pinpointing Claims Data'
SOrganization = claimsSheet.Cells(i, 1)
SBilling_Provider = claimsSheet.Cells(i, 2)
SDOS = claimsSheet.Cells(i, 3)
SMRN = claimsSheet.Cells(i, 4)
SPatient_Name = claimsSheet.Cells(i, 5)
SAudit_Program = claimsSheet.Cells(i, 6)
SAudit_Date = claimsSheet.Cells(i, 7)
SAuditor_Initials = claimsSheet.Cells(i, 8)
SChief_Complaint = claimsSheet.Cells(i, 9)
SMedically_Appropriate_History = claimsSheet.Cells(i, 10)
SMedically_Appropriate_Exam = claimsSheet.Cells(i, 11)

'Generating Output - Pintpointing Location in Report'
reportSheet.Cells(1, 3).Value = SOrganization
reportSheet.Cells(2, 3).Value = SMRN
reportSheet.Cells(3, 3).Value = SPatient_Name
reportSheet.Cells(4, 3).Value = SAudit_Program
reportSheet.Cells(5, 3).Value = SAuditor_Initials
reportSheet.Cells(6, 3).Value = SMedically_Appropriate_History
reportSheet.Cells(2, 7).Value = SBilling_Provider
reportSheet.Cells(3, 7).Value = SDOS
reportSheet.Cells(4, 7).Value = SAudit_Date
reportSheet.Cells(5, 7).Value = SChief_Complaint
reportSheet.Cells(6, 7).Value = SMedically_Appropriate_Exam

'Save the PDF'
reportSheet.ExportAsFixedFormat Type:=xlTypePDF, Filename:= _
    "C:\Users\ortegar\Pictures\" & SMRN, Quality:=xlQualityStandard, _
    IncludeDocProperties:=True, IgnorePrintAreas:=False, _
    OpenAfterPublish:=False

Next

End Sub
```

Comment: `With reportSheet`, `Dim lastRow As Long`, `lastRow = .Cells(.Rows.Count, 1).End(xlUp).Row`, `End With`, `For i = 2 to lastRow`.

Comment: try https://stackoverflow.com/questions/70564583/vba-loop-code-until-cell-is-empty-in-a-column